# view pdf in attachment

Tags: jsp

how

how to view pdf file on onclick of the button,one text box which i can able to select pdf file one hidden field which i can able to store path of this pdf, when i click a button it should concatenate both file name and path, and display the pdf file in pdf format

Comment: yes, one sentence on 3 lines. Rather unclear. Rephrase please, because it is not comprehensible right now.

Answer (score 0):

Its not text box you should file input element

and attach onclick event to button

that can be done either

or

document.getElementById('pdfDisplayButton').onclick=function(){}